# How to implement Ngx-Datatable server side pagination if pagination is not zero based

Tags: angular5, ngx-datatable

I am trying to implement server-side pagination in angular 5 based web app.

Problem is the API requires pagination to start from index 1 whereas the library "ngx-datatable" pagination is 0 based.

Here's my current implementation:

mycomponent.html

```
<ngx-datatable
    #usersTable
    class='material text-centered'
    [rows]='users'
    [columns]="usersColumn"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [externalPaging]="true"
    [offset]="page.offset"
    [limit]="page.pageSize"
    [count]="page.totalElements"
    (page)='fetchList($event)'>
 </ngx-datatable>
```

mycomponent.ts

```
page: any = {
  offset: 0,
  pageNumber: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  totalElements: '',
  sortBy: "id",
  sortOrder: "desc"
};

ngOnInit() {

this.usersColumn = [
  {
    name: 'S.NO',
    prop: 'sno'
  },
  {
    name: 'First Name',
    prop: 'firstName'
  },
  {
    name: 'Last Name',
    prop: 'lastName'
  },
  {
    name: 'Email',
    prop: 'email',
    width: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Action',
    cellTemplate: this.action
  }
 ];

  this.fetchList({ offset: 0 });
}

generateSerialNo(pageNo, size, i) {
  const index = i + 1;
  return pageNo == 1 ? index : (pageNo - 1) * size + index;
}

fetchList(pageInfo) {
  this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset + 1;

  const { pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder } = this.page);

  this.ListService.fetchList(pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder).subscribe(
  success => {
    if (success && !success['isError']) {
      const responseObj = success['responseObject'];
      if (responseObj) {
        const List = responseObj.content || [];
        const { totalElements } = responseObj;

        this.users = List.map((item, i) => {
          // set serial no. for user in current iteration
          const serialNumber = this.generateSerialNo(this.page.pageNumber, this.page.pageSize, i);
          return { sno: serialNumber, ...item };
        });

        this.page.totalElements = totalElements;
      }
    } else {
      this.toastr.error(success['message'], 'Oops!');
    }
  },
  errorResp => {
    const error = errorResp['error'];
    this.toastr.error(error['message'], 'Oops!');
  }
);
```

Now Say, there's an action column in the table which consists of buttons to block or unblock user which on click calls a function as follows:

```
blockUnblockUser(toBlock: boolean) {

  this.ListService.blockUnblockUser(toBlock, this.selectedUser.id).subscribe(
  success => {
    if (success && !success['isError']) {

      this.fetchList(this.page);

      this.utilService.closeModal();
      this.toastr.success(success['message'], 'Success!');
    } else {
      this.utilService.closeModal();
      this.toastr.error(success['message'], 'Oops!');
    }
  },
  errorResp => {
    const error = errorResp['error'];
    this.utilService.closeModal();
    this.toastr.error(error['message'], 'Oops!');
  });
}
```

Here's the problem. On page load, I get my list for page number one and page number one is the active page. Now Click on page number 2, in the request param of API this is what goes:
   `list?pageNumber=2&pageSize=10&sortBy=id&sortOrder=desc`
and in response, I get 3 data for page number 2 with 3 items.

Now if I click on the action button to either block or unblock particular user this is what sent in request params:
   `list?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&sortBy=id&sortOrder=desc`

and in response, I get data based on the page number 1 with 10 items.

but this time the active page in pagination is still "2"?

Please let me know where I am making mistake and how do I fix this. The backend team cannot make the pagination zero-based index for some reason.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Did you figure this out?